# Prototype add/remove id

Tags: prototypejs

I´m trying to add a click event via id to a div, so that when you click on it, it moves using effects.move, but after clicking on it the first time I want the id to be removed so that it doesn´t move anymore. So far I´ve tried using observe and stopObserving - and also removing the associated id so that it doesn´t move any more. I can´t figure out how to integrate a click event with an observe, without adding it directly to the div.

Any suggestions or relative links would be greatly appreciated!

link to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QN4TN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the observer removing the ID will not stop the event being handled. You should do something like this:

```
<div id="moveme">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('moveme').observe('click', function(ev) {
  ev.stop();
  ev.target.stopObserving('click');
  ... Call move function here ...
});
</script>
```

This will respond to the click by removing all the click handlers from the div (And then calling your scriptaculous code). If this is a problem, you should store the pre-bound handler and then pass that as the second parameter of the stopObserving method.